# Delay with in-app purchasing sandbox testing server

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, appstore-sandbox

I am having some problems connecting to the sandbox environment while testing my in-app purchasing. The problems are as follows:

1- In the ios simulator in xcode.. It takes too long to connect to the sandbox server. However once it does and I purchase the add-on everything goes smoothly from there. The problem here is that it takes a long time to connect to the apple server and confirm the purchase. The time it takes is around 2 to 3 mins.

2- I uploaded the binary on my iphone to test it, and on the iphone It also take a couple of minutes to connect to the server. But the problem is that after Apple asks me to confirm the purchase and I say yes. Nothing happens. I never get to enter my test user apple credentials and purchase the add on.

Has anyone had similar problems? Is there anyway to test why it is taking so long? Also is there any way to see if im getting any errors back when running the app on my iphone??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In setting, logout store account(Apple ID), and try to IAP login within application.It will help you.

Comment: I get similar experience now with IAP but for Mac App store app - it's totally non-responsive atm. Sure, there was always lots of weird things with the iOS IAP sandbox too, but I didn't see it this non-responsive. It just stalls at `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing`